# animation made in adobe flash professional

Tags: android, jquery, flash, animation

I have made 2 different animations in Adobe flash professional cs5.5 for an Android aplication.
And I want a code that makes it possible for a user of the app to play the animation as often they want, so if the user wants the animation to play 1 time the first animation will be playes, if the user wants to play it 2 times the animation 1 and 2 will be played, if the user wants the animation 3 times played the animation 1, 2 and 1 will be played and so on.
Can somebody help me with this problem and tell me if this is possible in jquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I was you, the way I would approach this is by having a keyframe after each of the animations where you can type some code.

On the menu page or where ever you have the code for how many times the code should run, define a variable and call it something like "runTimes" which should become the amount of times the animation should run.

At the end of the animations do a simple if statement to check what the value of "runTimes" is and then decrement it. Depending on the value, it should use gotoAndPlay/gotoAndStop.

So, put this on the keyframe after the first animation:

```
if (runTimes > 0) {
    runTimes--;
    gotoAndPlay(<FIRST FRAME OF SECOND ANIMATION>);
} else {
    gotoAndStop(<FRAME OF MAIN MENU>);
}
```

and this after the second animation:

```
if (runTimes > 0) {
    runTimes--;
    gotoAndPlay(<FIRST FRAME OF FIRST ANIMATION>); 
} else {
    gotoAndStop(<FRAME OF MAIN MENU>);
}
```

On the mainmenu frame, let's assume you have a textbox named "numTimes_txt" for the number of times to play and a button "playAnimations_btn" to start the animations.

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

var runTimes:int = 0;

playAnimations_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, playAnims);

function playAnims(e:MouseEvent):void {
    runTimes = parseInt(numTimes_txt.text);
    play(); // or gotoAndPlay(<FIRST FRAME OF FIRST ANIMATION>);
}
```

I haven't tested this as I don't have my IDE on me right now, but this should work if I understand the question properly.

Comment: thanks for putting the code back again but it doesn't work allright for instance if the first part ends at frame 14, so if I fill in "1" in the texbox the animation schould stop at frame 14 right? Which numbers schould I fill in in this code if (runTimes > 0) {
    runTimes--;
    gotoAndPlay(<FIRST FRAME OF SECOND ANIMATION>);
} else {
    gotoAndStop(<FRAME OF MAIN MENU>);
} and where schould I place the code because it isn't clear for me but a great thanks for bringing me so far

Comment: So you don't want it to go back to the main menu afterwards you mean?
If so, replace 'gotoAndStop(<FRAME OF MAIN MENU>);` simply with `stop();`.

You want to put the code on a keyframe **after** the **last** frame of the  animation. (Make sure it is a keyframe). (Also: if you are stopping on this frame, you will need to copy the contents across so it appears the same). [Example](http://i41.tinypic.com/n645y8.jpg)

Comment: man this is harder than I thought.. haha I don't get it right so I explain it: in total I have 48 frames, the frist part ends on frame 12 and the second on 35, the frames beyond the 35 are to loop the animation more than once, so if you fill in "3" it plays part 1,2 and ends at the third time, so... do you get it?? I know it is hard to understand without using any moral  communication but I am already very glad that you have helped me this far thanks for that

Comment: Hmm. I'm not quite sure if I do understand.
Currently the picture in my head of the project is that:
**1.** The user types in a number, let's call this _x_.
**2.** Flash then plays the two animations alternately until there have been played _x_ many times.
**3.** Once _x_ number of animations has played, Flash then returns to the main menu.
[I have created a quick example which will hopefully help you. You can adapt the code to fit your situation.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/g5vfju33hjfxe8f/stackoverflow-loopexample.fla)

Comment: Thank you very very very much!!!!! this is exactly what I needed, thanks for all the help and the patience!! I have changed the numbers so that the animation stops at the last frame and doesn't go back to the menu but the menu has to be in the screen all the time also while the animation is playing so if the animation is stopped at the last frame the user can fill in a a number again

Comment: so if the animation has stopped the begin menu has to show up again but the animation has to stand on the last frame as it was

Comment: I have adapt some so it should look something like this https://www.dropbox.com/s/useilapotfnf8x9/stackoverflow.fla but it is not working correctly you will notice when you test it that if you put in a number for the second time it will start with animation 2, and more importand that if you fill in "3" the animation plays animation 1 animation 2 and ends at the end of animation 1 but the transition from animation 2 to animation 1 is to abrubt, animation 2 schould play rewind and then start animation 1 but I don't know how to change this in the file

Comment: Okay, you now need to change the line that says `play();` (in the function `playBtnClick`) to 'gotoAndPlay(2);`. Note: if you use 1 instead of 2, it will sometimes stop on the first frame. There would be a work around for this however it would be rather complex.    
I'm not sure what you mean when you say the transition from animation 1 to animation 2 is too abrupt. Do you mean you want another kind of animation there or something?

Comment: I mean with that, that now when animation 2 is played and it goes to play animation 1 again, there has to be an piece of frames between such as animation 2 playing backwise so that becomes a smooth transaction in the case of this example It is not nessecarily a must but in my animation it is

Comment: Okay, take a look at my [updated example](https://www.dropbox.com/s/g5vfju33hjfxe8f/stackoverflow-loopexample.fla). Basically what happens is it extends the second animation and reverses it, but leaves the script where it was. After this reversed animation, it goes to and plays the second frame _without_ decrementing the `numLoops` variable.

Comment: thanks very much this was what I needed, I only want to apear some objects after the animation stops at the insert number and these object will be numbers a number has to be a link which starts a new animation, so for example if you end up with animation 2 on your screen, 4 numbers has to appear for example 1,2,3 and 4 if I klick on 4 the text animation 2 will flip over and some text will apear this text comes out of a database and is thus linked to the number which will apear

Comment: can you help me with that?

Comment: I'm not sure I really understand what you are asking to achieve there.

Comment: I will explain, I use the file you made for me so with the text animation 1 and animation 2 to make you understand what I mean. for example 1. you fill in the number "5" 2. the animation plays and you end up with the text animation 1 on your screen 3. on this moment the animation has stopped at the last frame of animation  1 and now the 4 objects has to appear 4. each of these object(for me it has te be numbers)you have to klick on the object so an animation gets activated(something as an field gets spread so the text is good visible) and text out of an xml file will be displayed

Comment: I hope it is clear to you other wise ask me and maybe we could start a chat if that would work out better

Comment: I think maybe an a _alpha code schould work to let the objects appear for example star_mc._alpha = 0; star_mc.onEnterFrame = function(){ if(this._alpha < 100){ this._alpha = this._alpha + 5; }} but the if function has to change to something as if the animation stops at that frame than let the _alpha work but I don't know how to achieve that

Comment: can you help me with that? otherwise I have to search for someone else who can help me because I don't have the skills to figure it out by my self

Comment: oke I understand I have to go to school my self too I have enough time its more that I like some movement in my project and cause of my lack of skills makes it that I'm asking you, but don't feel pushed! The thing I want to achieve is to let some objects to apear for example by using "alpha" but this is as2 the objects has to apear when the animation stops, on which frame it stops depands on the insert of the user if you remember?

Comment: I'm still not entirely sure what you are asking for precisely, but it does sound rather complex. I probably could help you but I'd have to fit it in around school, cadets and my own projects; so it may take some time so if this is an urgent or commercial project you should probably find someone else.

Comment: There is an alpha setting in AS3 aswell, it doesn't have an underscore prefixing it and it ranges from 0 to 1, instead of 0 to 100. Also, the enter frame functions look very different.
You need to create a function and assign an enterframe listener to the object. E.G. `star_mc.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, increaseAlpha); function increaseAlpha (e:Event):void { e.target.alpha += 0.05; // 5% }` (e.target refers to whatever object the listener is assigned to).

Comment: do you know something about sqlite because I find it very dificult http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19932304/error-1009-cannot-access-a-property-or-method-of-a-null-object-reference-when?noredirect=1#comment29661050_19932304 this is what I don't get, do you have an working code for sqlite in as3? it is very simple I only want some input text fields and an list field to display the inserted data, can you help me with that??